# Is there a way in Genero 4gl to create a drag and drop to insert files?

Tags: drag-and-drop, 4gl, genero

In know the method `ui.Interface.frontCall` to open the Windows-Explorer dialog and select files there, but I found nothing so far about an equivalent drag & drop method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at FGLDIR/demo/DragAndDrop/drag_from_desk and also read http://4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-fgl-manual-html/#fgl-topics/c_fgl_DragDrop_to_from_external_apps.html